# Is there a way to make Visual Studio Code `--goto` option the default?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often open files in VSC, in the format `filename:line`.

In order to make VSC go to the line, the option `--goto` is used. Is it possible to make it the default (aside from using a shell alias)?

Comment: in bash you can add a shell alias and it will add the `--goto`, in windows just write a little bat file `codeg.bat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no other way, other than using an alias. That's because, as the VS Code docs say: "*This argument is provided since some operating systems permit `:` in a file name.*"

If you don't want to use alias, you can shorten `--goto` to `-g`.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks :)